# QGIS Server project read from QWC2 doesn't display style

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qwc2

I'm trying to setup a QWC2 instance to read a QGIS Server project. Data is stored in a PostGIS database on the server. QGIS Server is up and running on a Debian 11 / Apache server.

I'm running QWC2 in development mode, didn't deploy yet. QWC seems to properly access the project: map extent is correct, layer tree also, including the scale dependent visibility for some layers as setup in the QGS project.

However none of the layers show up on the map beside the background layers.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I can provide QWC2's config.json & themesConfig.json if needed, or any other info, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue accessing the .pgpass file. I temporarily fixed it by deactivating it.